# Handle multiple recycler views in Android [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a situation where I have 3 RecyclerView on a single Layout. They are dependent on each other in a certain way. Data is coming from Room Database.

***Question Prototype (Problem statement)***: Let's say you have floors like (Floor1, Floor2, Floor3 etc.) and inside each floor you have rooms like (Room1, Room2, Room3 etc.) and inside each room you have People with name like (PersonA, PersonB, PersonC).
Given constraint is that : A person cannot be in two different rooms at same type.

**Edit 1**: Floors, Rooms and Persons are coming from the database in the form of a list of strings.

How would you show that using maybe ( a recycler view ) or anything on a single screen layout.
*There can be infinite number of floors, rooms and persons. But that information is fetch from a room database.*

**My approach** : (This is not a complete approach), But I am thinking like having one RecyclerView at the top which holds number of floors. We use a query to get the total floors from the database and sort them and display. During the `onBindViewHolder()` in the adapter for floors we have a condition which checks if there is a room associated with that floor and if there is then we make another query to fetch from database and show it (maybe using a new recycler View) but I don't know how to do that. Is nested recycler view a thing that can be used here.

It doesn't stop here as we make another query to database using that room name to find all the persons inside that room. Which is another recycler view.
I am thinking of applying this approach but I feel there are many stoppage for implementing this. And I am not sure if this is the way to handle such things.

*Image for reference* : [image]

I am looking for any information if you have been through any such situations then what approach did you followed. Is there any library that can be used to simplify this task or anything that you can provide knowledge of would be helpful. Thanks!

**Edit 2**: What's working now :
I tried implementing the nested recycler view. Things seems to be working fine as now I have two adapters currently (for floor and rooms) and I am inflating the floor adapter from the fragment and inflating the rooms adapter from `onBindViewHolder` of FloorsAdapter.

The problem I am facing now that inside recycler view I am getting the list of floors correctly but for the list of rooms(in child recycler view) I am only getting it for last floor.

**Check this image for reference** (Floor 2 and 1 also have rooms but I am only getting room C1 which is present in last floor which is 3) : [image: Image2]

Current code in Adapter :

```
class FloorsAdapter(
    private val controlPanelViewModel: ControlPanelViewModel,
    private val activity: FragmentActivity?
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FloorsAdapter.FloorViewHolder>() {

    private var floorList = emptyList<String>()

    private lateinit var roomAdapter: RoomAdapter

    inner class FloorViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): FloorViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ListItemControlPanelFloorsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
        return FloorViewHolder(binding.root)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FloorsAdapter.FloorViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = floorList[position]
        ListItemControlPanelFloorsBinding.bind(holder.itemView).apply {
            Timber.d("Current floor is $item, Floor List is : $floorList")
            tvFloor.text = item

            roomAdapter = RoomAdapter(controlPanelViewModel, activity)
            rvRoomControlPanel.adapter = roomAdapter
            rvRoomControlPanel.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

            controlPanelViewModel.getAllRooms(item).observeForever(Observer {
                Timber.d("List of rooms : $it")

                //Finding distinct rooms
                val distinct = it.toSet().toList()
                Timber.d("Distinct rooms list : $distinct")
                roomAdapter.roomList(distinct)
            })
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun floorList(floors: List<String>) {
        this.floorList = floors
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return floorList.size
    }
}

class RoomAdapter(
    private val controlPanelViewModel: ControlPanelViewModel,
    private val activity: FragmentActivity?
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomAdapter.RoomViewHolder>() {

    private var roomList = emptyList<String>()

    inner class RoomViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RoomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ListItemControlPanelRoomsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
        return RoomViewHolder(binding.root)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RoomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = roomList[position]
        ListItemControlPanelRoomsBinding.bind(holder.itemView).apply {
            Timber.d("Current room is $item")
            tvRoom.text = item
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun roomList(room: List<String>) {
        this.roomList = room
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return roomList.size
    }

}
```

Code in Fragment for inflating the Floors Adapter:

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.rvFloors.adapter = adapter
        binding.rvFloors.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        controlPanelViewModel.getAllFloors.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
            Timber.d("List is $it")
            //Remove duplicates from received list
            val distinct = it.toSet().toList()
            Timber.d("List after removing duplicates: $distinct")
            adapter.floorList(distinct)
        })
        Timber.d("Adapter: $adapter" )
    }
```

**Edit 3:** Going through the logs I found something which explains why is it happening. The list of floors is getting executed first because of this

```
controlPanelViewModel.getAllFloors.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
            Timber.d("List is $it")
            //Remove duplicates from received list
            val distinct = it.toSet().toList()
            Timber.d("List after removing duplicates: $distinct")
            adapter.floorList(distinct)
        })
```

As we are inflating the rooms recycler view from floors adapter here

```
  roomAdapter = RoomAdapter(controlPanelViewModel, activity)
            rvRoomControlPanel.adapter = roomAdapter
            rvRoomControlPanel.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

            controlPanelViewModel.getAllRooms(item).observeForever(Observer {
                Timber.d("List of rooms : $it")

                //Finding distinct rooms
                val distinct = it.toSet().toList()
                Timber.d("Distinct rooms list : $distinct")
                roomAdapter.roomList(distinct)
            })
```

It is going to be little delayed as data is being fetched from Room. So instead of doing something like (`Floor 1 -> Room1, Room2` we are getting something like (`Floor1, Floor2 -> Room3, Room4)`. The data about rooms for previous floors is getting lost.

What to do here? How to stop the execution of next floors unless we have fetched all the rooms and shown using the textview.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried replicate the exact scenario with one vertical recycler view and horizontal recycler view. Here is the thing, one vertical recyclerview for Floors. Then one in floor item, list of room item views can be added to vertical linear layout container. A single room item view contains horizontal recyclerview for person.

> Floor Vertical RV -> Adding Custom Room Items to Vertical LL -> Person
> Horizontal RV

Hope it helps.
[image]

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.mainRv)
        recyclerView.apply {
            adapter = FloorAdapter(getFloors(), this@MainActivity)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
        }
    }

    fun getFloors(): List<Floor> {
        val list = ArrayList<Floor>()
        for (i in 0 until 6) {
            list.add(Floor())
        }
        return list
    }
}
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/mainRv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapters:

```
class FloorAdapter(val floors: List<Floor>, val context:Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FloorViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FloorViewHolder {
        return FloorViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.floor_item,null))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FloorViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindView(floors[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return floors.size
    }

}

class PersonAdapter(val persons: List<Person>, val context:Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PersonViewHolder {
        return PersonViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.person_item,null))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PersonViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindView(persons[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return persons.size
    }

}
```

View Holders:

```
class PersonViewHolder(val view:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bindView(person: Person) {
        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.person_tv).text = "Person:${person.personId}"
    }
}

class FloorViewHolder(val view:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    fun bindView(floor: Floor){
        val str =  "Floor : ${floor.floorId}"
        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.floor).text = str
        view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.room_container).let { ll->
            ll.removeAllViews()
            floor.rooms.forEach{
                val myView= LayoutInflater.from(view.context).inflate(R.layout.room_item,null)
                myView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.room).text = "RoomId :${it.roomId}"
  

                  myView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.persons_rv)?.apply {
                        adapter = PersonAdapter(it.persons,view.context)
                        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)
                        setHasFixedSize(true)
                    }
                    ll.addView(myView)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Data Class:

```
       data class Floor(val floorId: Int = (0..900).random()) {
        var rooms = arrayListOf<Room>()
        init {
            for (i in 0 until 50) {
                rooms.add(Room())
            }
        }
    }
 data class Room(val roomId: Int = (0..900).random()) {
        var persons = arrayListOf<Person>()
        init {
            for (i in 0 until 200) {
                persons.add(Person())
            }
        }
    }
    data class Person(val personId: Int = (0..900).random())
```

floor_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/floor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/room_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floor"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

person_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="18dp"
    android:id="@+id/person_tv"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView>
```

room_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/room"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/persons_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/room" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable, but the problem is that data is not coming from a data class. It is live data and needs to be observed from view model. And data is very much dependent on each other. Like rooms depends on floors and further persons depends upon rooms.

As data is from live data, inside `onBindViewHolder` of floor class we need to observe the rooms and inside `onBindViewHolder` of room we need to observe Person. I am still working to figure this out.

Comment: This is what I think:
1. You should not observe the room db in the observer class.
2. You should create a query using joins from room db if you have 2 different table for floors and people
3. You should have a single source of truth only. You should get your data from db first(both floors and corresponding people of those floors) and them have a transformation layer which converts this object into UI object which you can pass it into the adapter.

Comment: ^^ This. Do not make your life more complicated. Tackle problems separately. Have a source of truth about your data. This source can be dynamic (observing) a DB or a timer or anything. Then transform that mess into something that helps you drive your UI the way you need it. When the data changes behind the scenes (or initiated by a user event like a click), simply update the data and let the "observer" pick the new values, retransform the (new) data, and push the new state down to your UI. Don't mix responsibilities or your code gets more complex at every involved layer.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I tried implementing it in a better way with ViewModel acting as a single class for providing all the information. Still got some issues. Can you please have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73318527/how-to-handle-data-in-3-nested-recycler-views-in-android-kotlin

Comment: @Gowtham K K and Pratham Khurana can you guys please also take look at the question here and provide any helpful comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73318527/how-to-handle-data-in-3-nested-recycler-views-in-android-kotlin

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a sample project and provide git repo link with your code? There might be small thing you are missing. Your way seems to be much tricky.