# onCreateViewHolder() of child recycler view not being called in Android [Kotlin]

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a nested recycler view structure. The data for the recycler view is coming from Room Database and it follows MVVM architecture with repositories and viewmodels.

I am able to inflate the parent recycler view and get the list on screen but the child recycler view is not being inflated. I can see the value being passed through the adapter by using logs. But that is not being used on `onBindViewHolder()` and neither `onCreateViewHolder()` is called

Any help would be appreciated.

My CODE:

Fragment :

```
class ControlPanelFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentControlPanelBinding? = null
    private val binding: FragmentControlPanelBinding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var controlPanelViewModel: ControlPanelViewModel

    //floor adapter
    private lateinit var adapter: FloorsAdapter

    //rooms adapter
    private lateinit var roomAdapter: RoomsAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentControlPanelBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        controlPanelViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[ControlPanelViewModel::class.java]
        adapter = FloorsAdapter()

        roomAdapter = RoomsAdapter()
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.rvFloors.adapter = adapter
        binding.rvFloors.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        ListItemControlPanelFloorsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).apply {
            rvRoomControlPanel.adapter = roomAdapter
            rvRoomControlPanel.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            Timber.d("Inside list item")
        }

        controlPanelViewModel.getAllFloors.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            Timber.d("List is $it")
            //Remove duplicates from received list
            val distinct = it.toSet().toList().sorted()

            Timber.d("List after removing duplicates and sorting: $distinct")
            adapter.floorList(distinct)

            for (i in distinct) {
                controlPanelViewModel.getAllRooms(i).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { rooms ->
                    Timber.d("Floor: $i, Rooms: $rooms")

                    val distinctRooms = rooms.toSet().toList()
                    roomAdapter.roomList(distinctRooms)
                })
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Parent recycler view adapter

```
open class FloorsAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<FloorsAdapter.FloorViewHolder>() {

    private var floorList = emptyList<String>()

    inner class FloorViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): FloorViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ListItemControlPanelFloorsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
        return FloorViewHolder(binding.root)
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FloorsAdapter.FloorViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = floorList[position]
        Timber.d("Current floor is $item, Floor List is : $floorList")
        ListItemControlPanelFloorsBinding.bind(holder.itemView).apply {
            Timber.d("Current floor is $item, Floor List is : $floorList")

            tvFloor.text = "Floor : $item"
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun floorList(floors: List<String>) {
        this.floorList = floors
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return floorList.size
    }
}
```

Child Recycler view adapter:

```
class RoomsAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomsAdapter.RoomsViewHolder>() {

    private var roomList = emptyList<String>()

    inner class RoomsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RoomsViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ListItemControlPanelRoomsBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return RoomsViewHolder(binding.root)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RoomsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Timber.d("Room List onBindViewHolder: $roomList")
        val item = roomList[position]
        ListItemControlPanelRoomsBinding.bind(holder.itemView).apply {
            tvRoom.text = item
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return roomList.size
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun roomList(room: List<String>) {
        this.roomList = room
        Timber.d("Room List: $roomList")
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


}
```

Fragment layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.controlPanel.ui.ControlPanelFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
            android:id="@+id/switchFactory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="Factory"
            android:textOff="OFF"
            android:textOn="ON"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnChooseFloor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/switchFactory"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/switchFactory"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/switchFactory" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvFloors"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_control_panel_floors" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

List Item for fragment recycler view(parent recycler view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFloor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:text="Floor 1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvRoomControlPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_control_panel_rooms" />


</LinearLayout>
```

List item for child recycler view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRoom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Conference Room"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit 1:
My entity :

```
data class AddedDevicesInformation(

    @ColumnInfo(name = "floor_name")
    var floorName: String = "",

    @ColumnInfo(name = "room_name")
    var roomName: String = "",

    @ColumnInfo(name = "machine_name")
    var machineName: String = "",

    @ColumnInfo(name = "device_name")
    var deviceName: String = "",

    @ColumnInfo(name = "factory_status")
    var factoryStatus: Boolean? = false,

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
) {
}
```

DAO query :

```
    //returns all rooms associated with a floor
    @Query("SELECT room_name from added_device_information where floor_name =:floor")
    fun readAllRoomsOnAFloor(floor: String): LiveData<List<String>>
```

Repository:

```
class ControlPanelRepository(private val devicesInformationDao: DevicesInformationDao) {

    fun getAllRooms(floor: String): LiveData<List<String>> = devicesInformationDao.readAllRoomsOnAFloor(floor)
```

ViewModel:

```
class ControlPanelViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    //repository instance
    val repository: ControlPanelRepository

    //Variable for getting all floors
    val getAllFloors: LiveData<List<String>>


    init {
        val database = PowerManagementDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        val dao = database.getAddedDevicesInformationDao()
        repository = ControlPanelRepository(dao)
        getAllFloors = repository.getAllFloors
    }

    fun getAllRooms(floor: String): LiveData<List<String>> {
        return repository.getAllRooms(floor)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each "floor" (row in the floor RecyclerView) has its own unique "room" RecyclerView, but you never attach an adapter to those room RecyclerViews. Instead, you inflate an unused "floor" layout in the Fragment and attach a room adapter to it. That layout will never be displayed anywhere so its adapter is never used.

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding.rvFloors.adapter = adapter
    binding.rvFloors.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

    // The problem is this part.
    // This view isn't shown anywhere, and the views inflated in FloorsAdapter
    // never get a RoomAdapter attached
    ListItemControlPanelFloorsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).apply {
        rvRoomControlPanel.adapter = roomAdapter
        rvRoomControlPanel.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        Timber.d("Inside list item")
    }
```

Each displayed floor layout is inflated in the floor adapter in `onCreateViewHolder` and the data for the floor then gets set in `onBindViewHolder`. This means you need to create a separate `RoomsAdapter` for *each* floor and attach it inside the floor adapter somewhere.

This makes accessing the room adapters more difficult with your current pattern, but if you make a `Floor` object that contains both its name and its list of rooms, then the floor object selected in `onBindViewHolder` can pass the list of rooms to its RoomAdapter. This means the `FloorsAdapter` would take a `List<Floor>` instead of `List<String>`. Then in the main fragment you only need to pass the list of `Floor` objects to the floor adapter and it will handle passing room lists on to the room adapters appropriately.

```kotlin
data class Floor(val name: String, val rooms: List<String>) {}
```

The floor adapter would look something like this:

```kotlin
// modify the ViewHolder to store the binding (so you don't have to
// re-bind the views so often) and store the room adapter for this
// floor. There should be one room adapter per floor.
inner class FloorViewHolder(val binding: ListItemControlPanelFloorsBinding, 
                            val roomAdapter: RoomsAdapter)
                            : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): FloorViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding = ListItemControlPanelFloorsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

    // Create one adapter per floor here
    val adapter = RoomsAdapter()
    binding.rvRoomControlPanel.adapter = adapter
    binding.rvRoomControlPanel.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    return FloorViewHolder(binding, adapter)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FloorsAdapter.FloorViewHolder, position: Int) {
    // for a given floor, set the rooms on that floor's room adapter
    val currentFloor = floorList[position]
    holder.roomAdapter.roomList(currentFloor.rooms)
    holder.binding.tvFloor.text = "Floor : ${currentFloor.name}"
}
```

Here's an example of how that might look in the ViewModel, when it constructs the list of Floor objects, and the activity would observe the `floorList` LiveData. Each `Floor` contains all the data (including nested data) that it needs to display.

```kotlin
private val floorListLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Floor>>()
val floorList: LiveData<List<Floor>>
    get() = floorListLiveData
        
fun load() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val floors = mutableListOf<Floor>()
        
        val floorList = dao.readFloors()
        
        for(floorName in floorList) {
            val rooms = dao.readRoomsInFloor(floorName)
            floors.add(Floor(floorName, rooms))
        }
        
        floorListLiveData.postValue(floors)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It may solve my final issue but I have few questions more questions:

1. How do I make this data class. Should I be observing the viewmodel here and then creating the list? I don't understand it completely.

2. There is one more layer of recycler view after this. So for each floor there is list of rooms and for each room there is a list of people. I should be making data class and adapters considering that.

Here is the main question if you could please take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73264932/handle-multiple-recycler-views-in-android-kotlin

Comment: I have also updated the question by adding the room db information and the repository and viewmodels. I would like to understand the architecture that I might follow to tackle this complete problem. Thanks a lot for your previous explanations.

Comment: I added a simple example showing how you might construct a list of Floor objects to show in your view model. If you don't understand how to make a list of objects from your Room database then you should ask a separate question specifically about that - don't keep editing the current question. The current question is "why aren't the nested recycler views working"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. Really helped me to understand the mistake. Finally I was able to inflate the views. Thanks once again :)

Comment: Please have a look at this question and provide any comments if possible : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73318527/how-to-handle-data-in-3-nested-recycler-views-in-android-kotlin